# Is it possible to solve for pressure loss in turbulent flow along a pipe purely analytically?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, flow, viscosity, turbulence

I understand it's possible to find pressure loss using formulas such as the Darcy Weisbach equation works with turbulence - but to my knowledge the friction factor is derived using empirical means.
Is there a purely math-based way to solve for pressure loss in turbulent flow along a uniform pipe (assuming the fluid is incompressible and steady)?

Comment: There are people who are studying turbulence mathematically by solving the detailed transient flow equations, but such computations are still very computationally intensive, and I know of no cases in which this has yet been accomplished successfully on a practical basis.

Comment: Ah I see, thank you!